# Sharepoint grant permission on item

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I a method for the lists and it works.
I'm trying to do the same for a SPWeb:

```
public static void assignPermissionsToItem(SPWeb selectedItems, SPPrincipal User, string SpRoleType)
{

}
```

Resolved.